# Proving that the gamma function is a certain limit

Tags: proof-writing, gamma-function

This time I want to prove that $\displaystyle \Gamma(x) = \lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow 0} \int_\varepsilon ^{1/\varepsilon} t^{x-1} e^{-t}$, I know this is true because we have defined $\displaystyle \Gamma(x) = \int_{\mathbb R_+}t^{x-1}e^{-t} dt$ but the thing is  how can I say this formally and using the fact that the function  $t\mapsto t^{x-1}e^{-t} $ is integrable on $\mathbb R_+ = (0,\infty)$, because I have the following result : [Prove that $ f:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ is integrable iff $\lim_{\epsilon\to0} \int_{[a+\epsilon,b-\epsilon]}f$ exists](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1206794/prove-that-fa-b-to-mathbbr-is-integrable-iff-lim-epsilon-to0-int) and I think this could help, Can you help me with this ?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: For what values of $x$? This is certainly not true for $\Re(x)<0$: the improper integral doesn't exist.

Comment: I am sorry, is for x>0 :) we are not in complex variable so x is real :)

Comment: So what can be done?

Comment: What, specifically, do you want to show? That the limit of the integral converges to something? That the limit satisfies properties that define the Gamma function, like $x \Gamma(x) = \Gamma(x+1)$?

Comment: No, that the limit is the gamma function :)

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $\varepsilon = 1/n$, so we are looking at
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{1/n}^n t^{x-1} e^{-t} \, dt $$

You probably want to show that you have a Cauchy sequence, viz., given $\delta>0$, there is an $M$ so that
$$ \left\lvert \int_{1/n}^{n} t^{x-1} e^{-t} \, dt - \int_{1/m}^{m} t^{x-1} e^{-t} \, dt \right\rvert < \delta $$
whenever $m,n>M$. Without loss of generality, take $n>m>M$. Then the left-hand side reduces to
$$ \left\lvert \int_{m}^{n} t^{x-1} e^{-t} \, dt + \int_{1/n}^{1/m} t^{x-1} e^{-t} \, dt \right\rvert \leqslant \left\lvert \int_{m}^{n} t^{x-1} e^{-t} \, dt \right\rvert + \left\lvert \int_{1/n}^{1/m} t^{x-1} e^{-t} \, dt \right\rvert \\
= \int_{m}^{n}  t^{x-1}  e^{-t}  \, dt + \int_{1/n}^{1/m}  t^{x-1}  e^{-t} \, dt,
 $$
and now we have to show these can be made small.

At this point it is sensible to integrate by parts, just to make $t^x$ an increasing function. This gives you
$$ \int_a^b t^{x-1} e^{-t} \, dt = \frac{1}{x}[t^x e^{-t}]_a^b + \frac{1}{x} \int_a^b t^x e^{-t} \, dt = \frac{1}{x}(b^x e^{-b}-a^x e^{-a}) + \frac{1}{x} \int_a^b t^x e^{-t} \, dt $$

At this point I'm going to forget about the $1/x$, since it is just a constant. For the interval $[1/n,1/m]$,
$$ \int_{1/n}^{1/m} x t^{x-1} e^{-t} \, dt = m^{-x} e^{-1/m} - n^{-x} e^{-1/n} + \int_{1/n}^{1/m} t^x e^{-t} \, dt \\
\leqslant m^{-x} + \int_0^{1/m} t^x \, dt,
$$
and it is obvious that both of these can be made as small as we like by choosing $m$ large enough.

Now, the other integral requires a different idea. My suggestion is to integrate by parts the other way: this trick only requires that we know that
$$ y^s e^{-y} \to 0 $$
as $y \to +\infty$, for any constant $s$. (There are plenty of places this is proved, including on this site.)

So what happens is:
$$ \int_m^n t^{x-1} e^{-t} \, dt = [-t^{x-1}e^{-t}]_n^m + (x-1)\int_n^m t^{x-2} e^{-t} \, dt \\
\leq n^{x-1} e^{-n} + (x-1)n^{x-2} e^{-n} + \dotsb + (x-1)(x-2) \dotsm (x-k)\int_n^m t^{x-k} e^{-t} \, dt,  $$
repeating this $k$(ish) times, where $k=\lfloor x \rfloor +1$ The first set of terms is basically a polynomial in $n$ of degree $k-2$, multiplied by $t^{x-k} e^{-n}$, and using the limit I mentioned, this can be made as small as we like by choosing $n$ large enough. The last term is the integral of a decreasing function since $x-k<0$, and hence is bounded by $ n^{x-k} \int_n^{\infty} e^{-t} \, dt $, which again can be made as small as we like.

Hence the improper integral is the limit of a Cauchy sequence, so it exists.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22886/discussion-on-answer-by-chappers-proving-that-the-gamma-function-is-a-certain-li).